# Docker - safe way to clean up overlay folder

Tags: docker, centos

I've discovered that my /var/lib/docker/overlay2 folder 2x times more than docker shows up   (15.7G vs 8.4G)

```
# pwd
/var/lib/docker
# du -d 1
4   ./swarm
28  ./volumes
12188   ./image
19312   ./buildkit
16  ./plugins
548 ./containers
15773828    ./overlay2 <---- HERE
4   ./runtimes
80  ./network
4   ./tmp
15806020    .
# docker system df
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          5         3         8.423GB   1.317GB (15%)
Containers      3         3         65B       0B (0%)
Local Volumes   0         0         0B        0B
Build Cache     19        0         0B        0B
```

Also i've tryed to find something old, but have nu luck there

```
# docker ps -a -q -f status=exited
# docker images -f "dangling=true" -q
# docker volume ls -qf dangling=true
```

So is there any way so safe clean up folder?

Comment: so `docker system prune`?

Comment: Total reclaimed space: 0B